# Calling the same code two ways causes architecture issue in test case

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, carthage

## Issue

I am running into a strange situation where I am either directly calling a block of code in a uint test case - or calling a wrapper around that code.  In the case of the wrapper the test will compile - in the case of calling it directly I am getting an architecture issue.

I am wondering if anybody can offer some insight

## Overview

I'm writing an iOS application to do some SFTP action and I'm using the [NMSSH library](https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH) which allows for SFTP.  I've included it via [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) and everything is working great.

My situation is that I've put together some code in my main target to test out the SFTP capabilities.

## Project Code

https://github.com/jeeftor/compileBug

## Source Code

```
import Foundation
import NMSSH

/**
 SFTP Data Transfer Provider is a way of getting SFTP Data
 */
public class SFTPFileDataProvider {

    private var privateKeyPath: String?
    private var publicKeyPath: String?
    private let keyPassword = ""
    private let userName: String
    private let host: String
    private let port: Int

    /**
     Initializes a new SFTP Connection with host and (optional) port

     - parameter host: hostname of SFTP server
     - parameter port: _OPTIONAL_ defaults to 22
     */
    init(host: String, port: Int = 22, userName: String) {
        self.userName = userName
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
    }


    /**
     Returns a NMSFTP session with the configured data elements

     - returns: a session that is hopefully connected
     */
    func ftpSession() -> NMSFTP {
        let c = NMSSHSession.connectToHost(self.host, port: self.port, withUsername: self.userName)
        c.authenticateByPassword("password")
        return NMSFTP.connectWithSession(c)
    }

    public static func test() {
        testFTP()
    }
}


class TMonkey {
    func test() {
        testFTP()
    }
}


func testFTP() {

    let sftp: NMSFTP = SFTPFileDataProvider(host: "test.rebex.net:22", userName: "demo").ftpSession()

    for f in sftp.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/") {
        print (f)
    }
}
```

## Test Code

In my test case I've tried to call the SFTP logic in 3 different ways.  The only way that actually compiles is if i call it like:

```
func test2Good() {        
    let t = TMonkey()
    t.test()        
    testFTP()
}
```

If I uncomment either of these guys:

```
// UNCOMMENT TO HAVE A BUILD FAILURE
func testCompileIssue() {
    let sftp = SFTPFileDataProvider(host: "test.rebex.net:22", userName: "demo")
}

// UNCOMMENT TO HAVE A BUILD FAILURE
func testStatic() {
    SFTPFileDataProvider.test()
}
```

I get the following error:

> ld: framework not found NMSSH for architecture x86_64

[image]

when I try to compile and run the unit tests

I'm at somewhat of a loss here because as far as I can tell the two "bad" calls are basically doing exactly the same things as the call the works.  They are both calling into the same code - yet two of them wont allow the code to compile.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?  Has anybody run into a similar issue?

Comment: Your compileTest project builds for iOS, yet x86_64 is an OS X architecture. I'd have to understand more about your project and build environment to know the exact issue, but you should be investigating this architecture discrepancy.

Comment: This is exactly why I am confused.  The test case "should" be building only ARM code - but depending on how i actually am trying to call the test code somehow the compiler decades it needs to link in an X86 Lib instead of an Arm one - and I did not build an x86 one